# React: Is it ok to pass a component to another component through the props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a component, for example `<Foo />` that renders something like this:

```
<div>
   <Bar />
   {/* ... */}
</div>
```

Would it be possible to pass Bar as a property of Foo? `<Foo Bar={Bar}/>`. So I can reference Bar during the render of Foo:

```
render() {
  const Bar = this.props.Bar;
  return (
    <div>
      <Bar />
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't know if this would be a good idea to be honest, just checking to see if somebody knows better than me.

The reason I would like to do something like this is because I want to test a component and was thinking on how to inject fake dependencies into the component. For a project I was thinking on using [Preact](https://preactjs.com/), which does not work with shallow render, therefore I was thinking on perhaps doing some kind of dependency injection.

Passing through the components that the component uses would allow me to fake them during testing, passing mocks.

Is this a good idea? Or not really the way to go?...

Comment: A HOC would be a better alternative to replicate similar behaviour. This article details such approach very well. https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.r4mbzunhu

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it could be a bad Idea.

When you build a *React* component, you're building a **Javascript** object with some syntax (JSX) which will be translated to plain **Javascript**. So passing a **React** component is like passing any **Javascript** object.

For information, that's the way [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) use to pass component in **Route**.

Comment: True, I've noticed that. And the children property is an array of components. But I have not seen the previous approach being used, so I am a little bit reluctant about it

Comment: The only bad thing I can think of here is that it makes it less readable. Here you will have to check the parent component to know what kind of element that is actually created here. 
This will be a much bigger problem if A LOT of components create their markup like this. (Scalability/readability)

Comment: I see... And wherever Foo is being rendered, you would have to pass Bar as well to be able to pass it to Foo as a property, I guess?...